# PHPbb redirect to certain page if its first of the month

Tags: php, html, redirect, phpbb

All,
I have been trying to get my instance of PHPBB to redirect to a certain page if it is the first of the month. All other days of the month I want the redirect to the index page.

I have tried modifying the includes/functions.php to include the redirect and the ucp.php page to include the new redirect.

includes/functions.php:

```
// The result parameter is always an array, holding the relevant information...
        if ($result['status'] == LOGIN_SUCCESS)
        {
            date_default_timezone_set('EST');
            $firstday = date('Y-m-01');
            $today = date('Y-m-d');
            if ($firstday == $today){
                $redirect = request_var('redirect', "{$phpbb_root_path}projects/index.$phpEx");
                $message = ($l_success) ? $l_success : $user->lang['LOGIN_REDIRECT'];
                $l_redirect = ($admin) ? $user->lang['PROCEED_TO_ACP'] : (($redirect === "{$phpbb_root_path}projects/index.$phpEx" || $redirect === "projects/index.$phpEx") ? $user->lang['RETURN_INDEX'] : $user->lang['RETURN_PAGE']);
            }
            else{
                $redirect = request_var('redirect', "{$phpbb_root_path}index.$phpEx");
                $message = ($l_success) ? $l_success : $user->lang['LOGIN_REDIRECT'];
                $l_redirect = ($admin) ? $user->lang['PROCEED_TO_ACP'] : (($redirect === "{$phpbb_root_path}index.$phpEx" || $redirect === "index.$phpEx") ? $user->lang['RETURN_INDEX'] : $user->lang['RETURN_PAGE']);
            }
            // append/replace SID (may change during the session for AOL users)
            $redirect = reapply_sid($redirect);
```

and the ucp.php:

```
case 'login':
        date_default_timezone_set('EST');
        $firstday = date('Y-m-30');
        $today = date('Y-m-d');
        if (($user->data['is_registered']) && ($today == $firstdate))
        {
            redirect(append_sid("{$phpbb_root_path}projects/index.$phpEx"));
        }
        else{
            redirect(append_sid("{$phpbb_root_path}index.$phpEx"));
        }
        login_box(request_var('redirect', "index.$phpEx"));
    break;
```

However using one or both of these does not return a successful redirect. The user is logged in and a

> This page cannot be displayed.

message shows up.

Is there a better way of doing this?
It would be nice to get this redirect to work.

Comment: you think way to complicated just use `if(date('d')==1){ }` date only accepts formats 30 or 1 isnt a format. so just compare the day (d) to 1.

Comment: Still. Same thing. Redirect doesn't perform correctly. Also, d in php returns 2 numeral values 'd' == 1 will not render 'd' == 01 will

Comment: try `$redirect = request_var('redirect', $phpbb_root_path.'projects/index.'.$phpEx);`

Comment: use `j` instead of `d`